Is a "factorizing" cover necessarily a base for the topology it generates?
Definition: given a set $X$, and $\mathscr{V}$ a set of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr{V}$ "covers" $X$, i.e. $\bigcup \mathscr{V} = X$, we say $\mathscr{V}$ has:

property $P$ if $\mathscr{V}$ is "factorizing", i.e. if for any $U \in \mathscr{V}$ and any finite subset $Y \subset U$, then there exists a function $f : Y \rightarrow \mathscr{V}$ such that

for each $y \in Y$ we have $y \in f(y)$ & $f(y) \subseteq U$; and
for each $y,y' \in Y$ if $y\neq y'$ then $f(y) \cap f(y') = \emptyset$.


property $Q$ if $\mathscr{V}$ is a base for the topology it generates on $X$ (so if for every $U,V \in \mathscr{V}$, given $x \in U \cap V$, there exists $W \in \mathscr{V}$ such that $x \in W$ and $W \subseteq U \cap V$).

We note that $Q$ does not necessarily imply $P$. E.g., suppose $X$ is a set of at least 2 elements, and take $\mathscr{V} = \{X\}$; this $\mathscr{V}$ is a base for the indiscrete topology on $X$ so $Q$ is satisfied; but clearly this $\mathscr{V}$ doesn't have property $P$.
My question is whether $P$ implies $Q$ in general? My guess is "no" but I'm not sure how to find a counter-example, nor how to approach proving the affirmative if it is true; would anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this question?

The collection of infinite subsets of the natural numbers provides a counterexample.
For any finite subset $Y$ of an infinite set of natural numbers $U$, you can simply partition $U - Y$ into $n$ infinite sets, where $n = |Y|$, then add an element of $Y$ to each one to get a collection of disjoint infinite subsets of $U$ which each contain exactly one element of $Y$, satisfying property $P$.
But if you set $U$ to be the set of even numbers and $V$ to be the set of odd numbers together with $0$, then their intersection is just $\{0\}$, which clearly cannot have an infinite subset, so property $Q$ is not satisfied.

I see, thanks for your help!
